# Change DC IP to public Server 2019

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I deploy AD DS on new VDS.
I delegated domain zone to a server. The problem is that I can't add pc to domain because I can't change domain controller private ip address to public address in DNS Manager. When I try to do it, is changes back after some time.

Tried adding external ip address to network adapter, it almost worked. Public IP appeared in the DNS Manager, but something is wrong with routing, I guess. If I configure DNS to listen only public ip, the connection with the DNS server losts.

Server OS: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Server Private IP: 10.128.0.10

Server Public IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Client OS: Windows 7, 10

What should i do to make DNS server point to Domain Controller (which is also Name Server) public IP instead of local IP ?

**Update**

I unchecked "Store the zone in Active Directory" in properties of the zone and finally it stopped reset ip to local. Now i can ping DC and zone through the internet but still can't add PC to domain. Now I'm getting error: “The network path was not found” on joining a domain
Here are the logs from clients NETSETUP:

```
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpDoDomainJoin
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'USER-PC'
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     OS Version: 6.1
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     Build number: 7601 (7601.win7sp1_ldr_escrow.191127-1706)
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     ServicePack: Service Pack 1
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     SKU: Windows 7 Максимальная
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpDomainJoinLicensingCheck: ulLicenseValue=1, Status: 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpJoinDomain
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     Machine: USER-PC
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     Domain: org.a-b-c.ru
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     Account: org.a-b-c.ru\Administrator
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135     Options: 0x27
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:31:135 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'org.a-b-c.ru' is valid as type 3 name
12/12/2020 18:57:31:276 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'org.a-b-c.ru' returned 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:31:276 NetpValidateName: name 'org.a-b-c.ru' is valid for type 3
12/12/2020 18:57:31:276 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'org.a-b-c.ru', flags: 0x40001010
12/12/2020 18:57:34:041 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC having account 'USER-PC$': 0x525, last error is 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:34:041 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
12/12/2020 18:57:34:041 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:34:041 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:34:041 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
12/12/2020 18:57:34:073 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'dc2.org.a-b-c.ru': 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:34:073 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\dc2.org.a-b-c.ru' in the specified domain
12/12/2020 18:57:34:073 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
12/12/2020 18:57:34:088 NetUseAdd to \\dc2.org.a-b-c.ru\IPC$ returned 53
12/12/2020 18:57:34:088 NetpJoinDomain: status of connecting to dc '\\dc2.org.a-b-c.ru': 0x35
12/12/2020 18:57:34:088 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x35
12/12/2020 18:57:34:088 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x35
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uncheck "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" on the domain controller to prevent the automatic update process in the DNS server?

**Edit:**
Please try: [Disable dynamic DNS updates](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-can-i-stop-my-windows-domain-controllers-dynamically-registering-dns-names) on Domain Controller:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
DWORD: UseDynamicDns 0
```

Reboot the server afterwards.

**Edit:**
Can you try the suggested solution from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/cannot-join-computer-to-domain)?

Comment: Nice idea, but it didn't work. After DNS Server restart IP changes back to local.

Comment: I guess server resolves itself and changes ip address to local, i tried edit hosts file, it also didn't work.

Comment: Also i turned off DNS Zone dynamic update - didn't work

Comment: In the dns server settings for the zone?

Comment: Yes, In the dns server settings for the zone

Comment: I created mentioned DWORD with 0 value and rebooted server - didn't work, IP still changes  to local after dns server restart

Comment: Do you see any entry in the event log of the dns server which causes the update? Can you track it down some further?

Comment: Nothing special, just a message that dns server started, finished the background loading and signing of zones.

Comment: After your update I added a new link to my answer.